# Using an anonymous type in a try catch c#

Tags: c#

I have struggled with this for years and normally just code my way around it, but it is time to solve it.

I am declaring a var that returns a new anon type and want to put it in a try/catch.
However, doing that means it is out of scope and cannot be seen by later code obviously.
Normally I just declare it first, then wrap the code in the try/catch then reassign inside of it like:

```cs
int result = 0;

try
{
    result = 77; //real code goes here
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

But here is my real code that I cannot figure out how to do something like that:

```cs
    try
    {
        var dt_stop = (from s in cDb.DistributionStopInformations
                       join r in cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders on s.RouteCode equals r.RouteCode
                       where r.RouteDate == s.RouteDate &&
                       r.BranchId == s.BranchId &&
                       (r.CompanyNo == companyNo && s.CompanyNo == companyNo)
                       && s.UniqueIdNo == uniqueId

                       select new
                       {
                           s,
                           r
                       }).Single();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { //no this will not be blank
        throw;
    }
```

UPDATE:
I do use dt_stop extensively after this, I am wanting to catch if there is a problem with it is assigned data.

I created the following class:

```
 public class StopData
{
    public DistributionStopInformation S { get; set; }

    public DistributionRouteHeader R { get; set; }
}
```

Then I attempt to use is like:

```
 StopData dt_stop = null;

        try
        {
            dt_stop = (from S in cDb.DistributionStopInformations
                       join R in cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders on S.RouteCode equals R.RouteCode
                       where R.RouteDate == S.RouteDate &&
                       R.BranchId == S.BranchId &&
                       (R.CompanyNo == companyNo && S.CompanyNo == companyNo)
                       && S.UniqueIdNo == uniqueId

                       select new StopData
                       {
                           S,
                           R
                       }).Single();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //YES....THERE WILL BE CODE HERE
            throw;
        }
```

I am getting
    Cannot initialize type 'StopData' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Comment: Do you *actually* have a catch block that does nothing but throw? If so, I'd strongly recommend removing it entirely.

Comment: If `dt_stop` is only filled with data within the `try/catch`, why would you use it afterwards? You would risk a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: you could declare a _dynamic_ variable before the try and use it afterwards

Comment: An anonymous object is closely coupled to the code that uses it, so you can put that code in the try catch block. If the generation and the use are so different that they should be separated, it's a sign that you should define a type (as many of the answers suggest)

Comment: @JonSkeet - no, it will be filled out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anonymous types are syntactic sugar to avoid you to name them. Anonymous types are used by the compiler to let you focus on what you want the program do.

For this reason, if you end up on referencing an anonymous type, it means that it is no longer anonymous:) Just give it a name and your issue goes away:

```
MyType dt_stop = null;
try
{
   dt_stop = (from s in cDb.DistributionStopInformations
                  join r in cDb.DistributionRouteHeaders on s.RouteCode equals r.RouteCode
                  where r.RouteDate == s.RouteDate &&
                  r.BranchId == s.BranchId &&
                  (r.CompanyNo == companyNo && s.CompanyNo == companyNo)
                  && s.UniqueIdNo == uniqueId

                  select new MyType
                  {
                      s,
                      r
                  }).Single();
}
catch (Exception)
{
   // here dt_stop can be used
   throw;
}
```

`MyType` can be a `System.Tuple` or a standard class. To preserve your semantics, you can make it a DTO (fill in your types as I cannot infer them from your source):

```
internal sealed class MyType
{
    public <The type of s> S {get; set;}
    public <The type of r> R {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I made a change but did it wrong...one moment please.

Comment: OK...it got further along but not quite there yet.

Comment: Well, can you try to change your type to use a constructor and initialize the parameters there. it should work, but I cannot test it right now.

Comment: that is what I was going to try and do, I started to but ran out of time for this.  I will have to swing back to it.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a default instance of your anonymous type like:

```
var temp = new {A = default(int), B = default(int)};
try
{
    temp = new  {A= 1, B=2};
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring an expando object outside?

```
dynamic dt_stop = new ExpandoObject();
```

It's a dynamic object which works at runtime

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of is using a dynamic type. So dynamic instead of var. But be aware that there's no intellisense on dynamic types.

Comment: Bruno's answer creating another instance of the anonymous type is fine here.

Comment: Sorry, saw it after sending my response (we responded at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Or use a `ValueTuple`.

```
var thing = default((int S, int R));
try
{
    thing = /*..*/.Select((s, r));
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```